# Chrome Failted to Load Resources Error 404 How to Fix for lightbox2

Tags: lightbox2

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) mistakes shows himself in console for Lighbtox.js. I downloaded the file and put into the my js file, I put the url path corrcetly to the bottom of my project after bootstrap and jquery js files.

I downloaded the file from original place.

Comment: Can you show some code.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it brother thank you. But still I have a problem...

This plugin doesn't work with last Jquery version, it wants me to use his jquery plus lightbox . js file. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: It actually doesn't give me a error message, it just opens the picture in a new tab instead of lightbox with jquery. When I used jquery-plus-lightbox.js from lightbox>dist>javascript file, it is fixed. But I don't want to use this unified javascript file because it is not updated jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a minimal working example as follows. It does work with the latest jquery. Make sure jquery script tag is before the lightbox script tag.

my index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="images/image-1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="TESTING">Image #1</a>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

File structure

[image: code]

And the result

[image: lightbox]